# URLStream and unicode

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am trying to send info using USLStream from flash client to JAVA server.
Some of the info is Chinese so i have to use Unicode.

How can i do that? now the Unicode info retrieved in the server is corrupted.

Comment: As Victor Welling already pointed out, Flash uses UTF-8 for sending and receiving data by default. How are you sending the data? Can you post the relevant code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Flash uses Unicode natively. Perhaps the [endian property](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLStream.html#endian) of the URLStream object is set incorrectly, you could try changing its value.